# Save to Excel - out of memory exception

Tags: c#

I get as much data from the database as 1400,000.

And we want to put them into different Excel files, but when I want to save the data in memory, in the loop iterates with, I encounter an out of memory  exception.

This is my code

```
private void FillingExcellSheetOld1(IRange cells, IEnumerable<object> sooratHesabList)
    {
        foreach (IEnumerable<object> row in sooratHesabList)
        {
            var colNumber = 0;
            foreach (var columnValue in row)
            {
                cells[rowNumber, colNumber, rowNumber, 48].Copy(cells[rowNumber + 1, colNumber, rowNumber + 1, 48]);//ToDo

                cells[rowNumber, colNumber].Value = columnValue?.ToString();
                colNumber++;
            }

            rowNumber++;
        }

        ClearMemory(sooratHesabList.ToList());
    }

    private void ClearMemory(List<object> lista)
    {
        int identificador = GC.GetGeneration(lista);
        lista = null;
        GC.Collect(identificador, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    }

 sooratHesabList.Count()=1400000
```

Comment: Automating Excel like this is rarely a good idea. There's usually a better way to load data into Excel. For example, you can load the data into an array and set the data in a single call.

Comment: You could copy the entire data in CSV format in the clipboard and paste it on the Excel sheet.

Comment: `GetGeneration()` returns the age (generation) of the object you pass to it and won't (at least, not according to the documentation) inspect the contents of collection types.  So, you are creating a (large) list just to ask how old it is, which is not useful information.

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable.ToList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netcore-3.1) creates a copy of the collection. And GC.Collect only collects objects which are not reachable.  So you would call it after FillingExcellSheetOld1 when you know that there are objects on the heap that take up a lot of memory, and are not reachable from any application root.